# SQL query count data from exact twelve months before

Tags: mysql, sql, database, group-by, subquery

I am trying to count total email of customer that has booked till this February 2020 from February 2019.
Each column should display total count of email following month name and 12 months back from that month name.

Table that I am using

[MYSQL TABLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y1IQb.png)

Query that I am using right now is

```
SELECT sub.monthNameYear, sub.monthName,        
       COUNT(*),
       (SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER (ORDER BY sub.monthNameYear)) as incrementBooking
FROM (SELECT DATE_FORMAT(`reservation_for`,'%Y-%m') as monthNameYear,
             DATE_FORMAT(`reservation_for`, '%M %Y') as monthName, 
             email,
             COUNT(*) AS cnt
      FROM `reservations`
      GROUP BY email, DATE_FORMAT(`reservation_for`, '%Y-%m'),
            DATE_FORMAT(`reservation_for`,'%M %Y')
      HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 
     ) sub
GROUP BY sub.monthNameYear, sub.monthName;
```

The result that I get from this query is
[image: Result generated from my query]

The result that I want to get followed by 12 months is

[image: count email following twelve months]

Comment: I don't understand the calculations.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I am trying to count total email from Jan 2019 - Jan 2020 , Feb 2019 - Feb 2020 and March 2019 - March 2020.

Comment: . . And how is "16" calculated?

Comment: @GordonLinoff 16 is just the total count of an email, its a random I have defined. Actually I need help on getting dates only January 2019 - January 2020 , Feb 2019 - Feb 2020 and March 2019 - March 2020.

Comment: @GordonLinoff hey can you please help me with this . I just updated my table image for you .

Answer (score 0):

```
select t1.monthNameYear as FromYear, count(*) as Count
from reservations`t1
inner join
reservations t2
where datediff(month, t1.monthNameYear, t2.monthNameYear)<12 
and datediff(month, t1.monthNameYear, t2.monthNameYear)>=0
group by t1.monthNameYear
```

Is this what you wanted?

Comment: it gives me an error with invalid date diff function.